# Criterion for normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, normal-subgroups

I'm reading Burton's book "Introduction to Modern Abstract Algebra", and I have a question about the criterion for normal subgroups. Theorem 2-32 of the text states:

A subgroup $(H,*)$ of a group $(G,*)$ is normal iff $a * H * a^{-1} \subseteq H$ for every $a \in G$.

I understand the proof, but I am confused about the relevance of the reverse inclusion $H \subseteq a * H * a^{-1}$. I think it holds for a normal subgroup:

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the inclusion $H \subseteq a * H * a^{-1}$ holds.

proof. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and pick an arbitrary $h \in H$. Then $h * a = a * h_1$ for some $h_1 
\in H$. Thus $h = a * h_1 * a^{-1} \in a * H * a^{-1}$, and
therefore $H \subseteq a * H * a^{-1}$. $\blacksquare$

This seems then, that the inclusion $a * H * a^{-1} \subseteq H$ implies the inclusion $H \subseteq a * H * a^{-1}$. That is, $a * H * a^{-1} \subseteq H$ implies
$a * H * a^{-1} = H$.

proof. Suppose that $a * H * a^{-1} \subseteq H$. Then by Theorem 2-32, we see that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. By the above proof, we have the inverse inclusion $H \subseteq a * H * a^{-1}$, and therefore $H = a * H * a^{-1}$.  $\blacksquare$

Am I making a mistake here? The more important inclusion seems to be $a * H * a^{-1} \subseteq H$. Are there subgroups $H$ of $G$ that are not normal, but satisfy
$H \subset a * H * a^{-1}$. I mean here that $H$ is a proper subset of $a * H * a^{-1}$, so that $a * H * a^{-1}
\nsubseteq H$. Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: You are right, one can prove that the following are equivalent:
1) $N$ is normal in G;   

2) $\forall a\in G$ it holds that $aNa^{-1} \subseteq N$;   

3) $\forall a\in G$ it holds that $N \subseteq aNa^{-1}$;   

4) $\forall a\in G$ it holds that $N = aNa^{-1}$;

Comment: It seems that the utility in Theorem 2-32 of the book is that there is less to prove by concentrating on only one of the inclusions, say $a N a^{-1} \subseteq N$.